# PHP Set Variable On MYSQL Data

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my php code, I am currently having.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "123";
$dbname = "db";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$sql = "SELECT fontsize FROM fb_test WHERE id = 15 ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row["fontsize"];
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

I Want To Do Something Like This

```
$var = echo $row["fontsize"];
....
....
imagettftext($this->fond,$var,0,200,400,$textcolor,$font,$item_text);
```

can someone help me for doing this? I tried everthing but not working please if someone know help me

Comment: Lose the echo; e.g. $FontSize = $row['fontsize'];

Answer (score 1):

$var =  $row["fontsize"];

imagettftext($this->fond,$var,0,200,400,$textcolor,$font,$item_text);

### remove the echo and use.

echo is useful only during printing the value on screen.